# How to convert NSDecimalNumber to NSNumber

Tags: swift, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

How to convert NSDecimalNumber To NSNumber? I have a NSDecimalNumber created inside a method which have to return a NSNumber object which can be checked later with [ ... isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    id rn = [self haveToBeNSNumber];
    
    if ([rn isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"It's NSNumber class object");
    }
    
    return YES;
}

- (NSNumber *)haveToBeNSNumber {
    
    NSDecimalNumber *dNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"123.22"];
    
    return dNumber;
}
```

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber` is already a subclass of `NSNumber` and will return YES when checked with `[x isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]`.  What is your issue?

Comment: `isKindOfClass:` is true if the object is a subclass of the class you are checking, `isMemberOfClass:` would return false in that case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is wrong with what you have?

As @dan states `NSDecimalNumber` is a `NSNumber`, that is a `NSDecimalNumber` responds to all the methods of a `NSNumber`.

You can cast the return type if you need to:

```
return (NSNumber *)dNumber;
```

Re rounding and accuracy: `NSDecimalNumber` in an exact decimal representation of the value,  `NSNumber` is a close binary representation of the value, most decimal numbers that are not integers can not be represented with complete accuracy in binary (base 2).

You control the displayed format with `NSNumberFormatter`. NSLog used the `description` method for display and formats the number the Apple developer liked.

Answer (score 0):

##### Swift

Since `NSDecimalNumber` is actually a subclass of the `NSNumber`, you can upcast it easily like:

```
let decimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(integerLiteral: 12)

let number = decimalNumber as NSNumber //  Upcast like this
```